# Apply changes without restarting project visual studio for mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Mac to develop net core MVC, and I'm struggling with restarting the project after I made the changes on **controllers** or **models**.
For comparison, asp.net in windows. I just need to register the project folder to IIS and I can access it trough browser with "localhost/myproject". And when I do the changes on backend and rebuild, it directly apply the changes.

Is there any way that I can duplicate the way windows does in mac?

Answer (score 1):

When you change back-end server side code, the c# must be recompiled and this cannot be done without restarting the app. Hot reloads are supported for front end changes to HTML, CSS, and Javascript files however.

Comment: thanks for answering @jawsofdoom. I just update my question. What I mean is how to configure the mac os like the way windows configure in IIS.